# How should database connection failure be handled in OSGI?

Tags: osgi, datasource

1. If I expose DataSource as a service in OSGI, how should I handle database connection failure? Should I configure an interceptor of the DataSource service, which would catch database connection failure exception and unregister the DataSource service? Or would OSGI container handle the exception for me?
2. How should I configure the consuming service, so that it would be able to survive unavailability of the DataSource service, and allow user to re-try the transaction again?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle unexpected exceptions in the same way as you do when you do not use OSGi.

You should use connection-pool and register that as an OSGi service. It will handle connection failures for you. You must always close the connection, even if there is an exception during using that connection. (in finally block before java 6 and by using a try-with-resources block after java 7). Connection pools provide their functionality by implementing DataSource interface.

There are many connection-pools. You can google for them.

I implemented two OSGi components based on commons-dbcp. One for pooling regular DataSources and one for pooling XADataSources. The component picks up the original DataSource/XADataSource OSGi service, than registers a new pooled-DataSource OSGi service.

You can find the source of the module here: https://github.com/everit-org/commons-dbcp-component

It is available at maven-central here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.everit.osgi%7Corg.everit.osgi.jdbc.commons.dbcp%7C2.0.1%7Cbundle

After dropping the jar into your OSGi container, you will see the configuration possibilities of the components at the Configuration page of WebConsole (if you have webconsole).

Comment: >>It will handle connection failures for you.<< Are you saying that OSGI container will catch database connection failure exception and unregister the DataSource service?

Comment: No. The pooled-datasource will behave as you configure it. E.g.: It can run a check SQL before providing any connection and wait for timeout if the database is not available. The DataSource service remains registered even if the database is not available.